# parallel installation of another python version in Linux(RHEL)

Tags: linux, python-2.7, rhel

In my RHEL linux python 2.6 is installed. I want to do a parallel installation of python 2.7 along with pip. Could you please guide me in right direction.

Comment: For my (data/analytics-oriented) purposes, I've always just installed [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#_unix). It has some packages I don't need, so I guess it's "heavy" in that respect, but it's quick and easy for provisioning purposes. Just make sure you've got the Anaconda interpreter appearing first in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Red Hat Software Collections - http://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/overview/.  This is exactly for parallel install of newer versions.  For Python, there's 2.7 and 3.4 (maybe 3.3 too - I've forgotten). Other stuff too. HTH.

And - it's part of RHEL subscription.  It's still Yum install, but a bit different.  Here are the steps for Python 3.4, but you can follow for 2.7: http://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/get-started-rhel7-python/